# MVC5 FullCalendar not populating

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, visual-studio, fullcalendar

I'm very new to MVC and I am trying to do the following tutorial in MVC5 to learn how to create a booking system [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/638674/Full-calendar-A-complete-web-diary-system-for-jQue)

I have downloaded Full Calendar and Twitter Bootstrap and pasted the CSS and JS files into the Content and Scripts folder.

I have replaced the code in the BundlesConfig with

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Optimization;

namespace FullCalendar_MVC
{
public class BundleConfig
{
    // For more information on Bundling, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=254725
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/scripts").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
            // needed for drag/move events in fullcalendar
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js",
                    "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                    "~/Scripts/bootstrap-modal.js"
                    ));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                "~/Content/site.css",
                "~/Content/bootstrap.css"
                ));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/themes/base/css").Include(
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.core.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.resizable.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.selectable.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.accordion.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.autocomplete.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.button.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.dialog.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.slider.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.tabs.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.datepicker.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.progressbar.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.theme.css"));
    }
}
}
```

and my Home/Index view is

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}


<div id='calendar' style="width:65%"></div> 

@section scripts{

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            defaultView: 'agendaDay',
            editable: true,
            allDaySlot: false,
            selectable: true,
            slotMinutes: 15,

        });

    })
</script>
}
```

When I run the application the calendar is not populating at all, just a grey button and "application name" appears. Any advice on where im going wrong will be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Comment: What errors are you getting in the browser console? (F12 > Console). I also cannot see `fullcalendar.js` in your Bundles? You have also not rendered any bundles on that view

Comment: Im getting the following errors: http://localhost:53178/bundles/jquery Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost:53178/bundles/bootstrap Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
Index:60 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
http://localhost:53178/img/glyphicons-halflings.png Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Where are you rendering your bundles? in the `_layout`? if so post it

Comment: @JamieRees thanks I had not rendered the bundles. I have just added in the following to the index view - @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/fullCalendar.js")  but it is still not populating

Comment: But you don't have a bundle called fullCalendar.js in your BundleConfig?